# Fluid keyboard input in GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, graphics, 2d

I'm developing a 2D program using OpenGL in C++. I'm using the Glut keyboard function. Its problem is that it can only respond to one key at a time.

Example:
when I press UP and RIGHT at the same time, it doesn't move diagonally as expected, but moves either up or right.

My switch statement looks something like this:

```
case GLUT_KEY_UP:     

    f.Move(UP);
    break;

case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: 
    f.Move(DOWN);
    break;
```

The `Move()` function adds or subtracts the (x,y) value of the object.

Is the problem in my handling(the switch statement)? Or is Glut's kb function just limited?

Is there any other way to get around this? I really don't want to waste time trying to figure it out when the problem is in the library itself and a better solution can be found somewhere else.

Comment: Why would someone down vote this? What a brainless loser.

Comment: Now, now. comments like that aren't going to garner you upvotes. Or anything other than more downvotes for that matter.

Comment: @Hex4869: Perhaps they had visions of spilling something into their keyboard... that is the first thing that came to my mind when I read the title, even though I knew better ;)

Comment: lol, "fluid" does sound like a bad choice of a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to track the state of the keys rather than doing something immediately the instant the key is pressed.

I'm sure someone else can do a better job explaining, but basically, it looks like you're currently telling the computer to move (e.g. 10 pixels) immediately in the direction corresponding to the key. If you really think about it, then there's not a possible way to move diagonally because that isn't even a concept that the computer knows about.

You want to think about physics. Velocity, forces (remember, acceleration is the time-derivative of velocity, and velocity is the time-derivative of position). Then you can come up with a scheme for how to give the computer the knowledge of arbitrary directions rather than 4 individual hard-coded actions to perform.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, now that I had my coffee and spent some time thinking about it, it seems my logic or handling method is a bit flawed. I think I have an idea now.